# How to notify a Repository/ViewModel from a DataSource?

Tags: android, mvvm, repository, datasource, viewmodel

I am using `LivePagedListBuilder` to build a `LiveData<PagedList<String>>` inside a `Repository` and send it to a `ViewModel`.

`Repository` in turn fetches the data from a `PositionalDataSource` which is implemented in the `DataSource` using `loadInitial()` and `loadRange()` methods.

Now, if the Data in the DataSource changes, how to notify this from DataSource to Repository/ViewModel so that a new data request can be initiated?